# heroku django collectstatic error

Tags: django, heroku

i'm trying to run collect my static files on heroku so i ran the command:

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

my settings file is:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))   
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
# define the directory which all upload files will be saved
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'MyApp/media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/MyApp/media/'
```

and i got the following error message:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/MyApp/static'
```

what does this mean?

why should i have a "static" file in "/app/MyApp"? isn't it supposed to be the

STATIC_ROOT?

full traceback:

```
Running `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` attached to terminal... up, r
```

un.9966

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
      execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django/core/management/_
_init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django/core/management/_
_init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django/core/management/base.py",
line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File     "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django/core/management/base.py",     line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django/core/management/base.py",     line 533, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 168, in handle_noargs
collected = self.collect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 98, in collect
for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 111, in list
for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 27, in get_files
directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django/core/files/storage.py",     line 270, in listdir
for entry in os.listdir(path):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/CTFdj/static'
```

edited:
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/CTFdj/static' =>>

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/MyApp/static'

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Your `STATIC_ROOT` is wrong. it should be the path where the collected static directory will be served.

Comment: what do you mean? doesn't my STATIC_ROOT declaration mean that my files will be served in the main project directory under the "staticfiles" directory? can you give me an example for a good declaration?

Comment: @brad, I guess I shouldn't say wrong, because it might works also, but I am unsure about the effect of having **relative path**. The documentation says it should be an **absolute path**

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your getting that error because your `BASE_DIR` is not setup correctly for your project structure.  Try running `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` locally to see if you get the same error.  You can also `print(BASE_DIR)` in `settings.py` to check if it's pointing to the correct location, and that the `static` folder is actually in that directory.  For my projects, I have the settings file several levels deep, but the `static` directory is at the root of the project, so my settings look like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))) // base_dir/subdir/settings/settings.py
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), // base_dir/static
)
```

Also, for my Heroku apps, I join `BASE_DIR` and `staticfiles` together for `STATIC_ROOT` like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

On another note, I should warn you that you cannot upload media files directly to your Heroku app like you currently have setup with `MEDIA_ROOT`.  Heroku uses an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) that discards files you write to it after the dyno is stopped or restarted.  You'll need to use a 3rd party service like Amazon S3 to upload user submitted media files.  The [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages) app can help with the integration.

Answer (score 0):

I might not be able to answer why it is looking at `/app/CTFdj/static`, but one possible reason is because your `STATIC_ROOT` might have been configured wrongly. It should be [the absolute path where the collected static will be copied to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT).  Have a look at how I normally organize my [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://github.com/9gix/djskel/blob/master/project_name/settings.py#L52-L68). Hope this helps.